Why isn't my laptop suspending when I'm closing the lid?
I have a Thinkpad T14s (g4) and my computer wont suspend when I close the lid. There has been an option to select what should happen when I close tid, but I can't find anything in the Power settings.
I want it suspend when I close the lid.

I'd expect it to suspend after the lid is closed, not while ...
